# Is there a way to check when the OS was installed?

Tags: command-line, log

I was wondering if there is a way to check the date the OS was first installed. Or maybe when it was first booted. I can't remember when i did d installation n i was just wondering if there was a way to find out.

Answer (score 8):

Use this command:

```
ls -al /var/log/installer/syslog
```

Creation date of installer log can tell you the installation date (since it's not modified after that).

[image]

Found here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10591868&postcount=5

---

Another solution is using this command:

```
ls -lt /usr/share/doc
```

Above of the default documents you can find creation date of documents for first installed applications.

[image]

I'm using ubuntu 10.04 so `2010-04-29` is shown for default documents.

Found here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=3784265&postcount=8

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any docs about this but it seems that on Ubuntu the files in  /var/log/installer/ can tell you about the installation.